# Optimization issues using Barnes-Hut for graph placing

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I've been trying to work out the problem of Force-Directed graph/Barnes-Hut in my graph visualization app. I've checked so far octree creation, and it looks correctly (tree is represented by boxes and circles are my graph nodes):
[image: Quadtree test]
Fields in my `Quadtree` are following:

```
class Quadtree
{
    public:
        int level;
        Quadtree* trees[2][2][2];
        glm::vec3 vBoundriesBox[8];
        glm::vec3 center;
        bool leaf;
        float combined_weight = 0;
        std::vector<Element*> objects;
        //Addition methods/fields
    private:
    //Additional methods/fields
    protected:
}
```

This is how I am adding elements recursively to my quadtree:

```
#define MAX_LEVELS 5

void Quadtree::AddObject(Element* object)
{
    this->objects.push_back(object);
}

void Quadtree::Update()
{
    if(this->objects.size()<=1 || level > MAX_LEVELS)
    {
        for(Element* Element:this->objects)
        {
            Element->parent_group = this;
            this->combined_weight += Element->weight;
        }
        return;
    }

    if(leaf)
    {
        GenerateChildren();
        leaf = false;
    }

    while (!this->objects.empty())
    {
        Element* obj = this->objects.back();
        this->objects.pop_back();
        if(contains(trees[0][0][0],obj))
        {
            trees[0][0][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][0][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][0][1],obj))
        {
            trees[0][0][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][0][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][1][0],obj))
        {
            trees[0][1][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][1][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[0][1][1],obj))
        {
            trees[0][1][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[0][1][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][0][0],obj))
        {
            trees[1][0][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][0][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][0][1],obj))
        {
            trees[1][0][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][0][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][1][0],obj))
        {
            trees[1][1][0]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][1][0]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        } else if(contains(trees[1][1][1],obj))
        {
            trees[1][1][1]->AddObject(obj);
            trees[1][1][1]->combined_weight += obj->weight;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<2;k++)
            {
                trees[i][j][k]->Update();
            }
        }
    }
}

bool Quadtree::contains(Quadtree* child, Element* object)
{
    if(object->pos[0] >= child->vBoundriesBox[0][0] && object->pos[0] <= child->vBoundriesBox[1][0] &&
       object->pos[1] >= child->vBoundriesBox[4][1] && object->pos[1] <= child->vBoundriesBox[0][1] &&
       object->pos[2] >= child->vBoundriesBox[3][2] && object->pos[2] <= child->vBoundriesBox[0][2])
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

As you can see on the picture nodes are very clustered. I've been trying to figure out the way to fix my repulsion force calculations, but it still not working and result is still this same.

So how I'm calculating it:

First in my main file I am running loop through all graph nodes:

```
for(auto& n_el:graph->node_vector)
{
    tree->CheckNode(&n_el);
}
```

Next in my `Qyadtree` class, (`tree` is this class object), I have this recursive method:

```
void Quadtree::CheckNode(Node* node)
{
    glm::vec3 diff = this->center - node->pos;

    double distance_sqr = (diff.x * diff.x) + (diff.y*diff.y) + (diff.z*diff.z);
    double width_sqr = (vBoundriesBox[1][0] - vBoundriesBox[0][0]) * (vBoundriesBox[1][0] - vBoundriesBox[0][0]);
    if(width_sqr/distance_sqr < 10.0f || leaf)
    {
        if(leaf)
        {
            for(auto& n: objects)
            {
                n->Repulse(&objects);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            node->RepulseWithGroup(this);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
            {
                for(int k=0; k<2; k++)
                {
                    trees[i][j][k]->CheckNode(node);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I have two methods calculate repulse force depending on the fact if it's between group and node or between two nodes:

```
double Node::Repulse(std::vector<Node*>* nodes)
{
    double dx;
    double dy;
    double dz;
    double force = 0.0;
    double distance_between;
    double delta_weights;
    double temp;
    for(auto& element_node:*nodes)
    {
        if(this->name == element_node->name)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(!element_node->use) continue;
        delta_weights = 0.5 + abs(this->weight - element_node->weight);
        dx = this->pos[0] - element_node->pos[0];
        dy = this->pos[1] - element_node->pos[1];
        dz = this->pos[2] - element_node->pos[2];
        distance_between = dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz;
        force = 0.19998 * delta_weights/(distance_between * distance_between);
        temp = std::min(1.0, force);
        if(temp<0.0001)
        {
            temp = 0;
        }
        double mx = temp * dx;
        double my = temp * dy;
        double mz = temp * dz;
        this->pos[0] += mx;
        this->pos[1] += my;
        this->pos[2] += mz;
        element_node->pos[0] -= mx;
        element_node->pos[1] -= my;
        element_node->pos[2] -= mz;
    }
}

void Node::RepulseWithGroup(Quadtree* tree)
{
    double dx;
    double dy;
    double dz;
    double force = 0.0;
    double distance_between;
    double delta_weights;
    double temp;

    delta_weights = 0.5 + abs(this->weight - tree->combined_weight);
    dx = this->pos[0] - tree->center.x;
    dy = this->pos[1] - tree->center.y;
    dz = this->pos[2] - tree->center.z;
    distance_between = dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz;
    force = 0.19998 * delta_weights/(distance_between * distance_between);
    temp = std::min(1.0, force);
    if(temp<0.0001)
    {
        temp = 0;
    }
    double mx = temp * dx;
    double my = temp * dy;
    double mz = temp * dz;
    this->pos[0] += mx + this->parent_group->repulsion_force.x;
    this->pos[1] += my + this->parent_group->repulsion_force.y;
    this->pos[2] += mz + this->parent_group->repulsion_force.z;
}
```

In case this idea:

```
if(width_sqr/distance_sqr < 10.0f || leaf)
    {
        if(leaf)
        {
            for(auto& n: objects)
            {
                n->Repulse(&objects);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            node->RepulseWithGroup(this);
        }
    }
```

is not clear it is because I've figured out, that there might be actually multiple elements in one tree leaf. That might happen if the maximum level might be already reached and still elements are in one box. Then I need also to calculate force within box against nodes inside.

What's more is bothering me is the speed of this approach (and it's indicating that octree is not working correctly) is the speed. This is simple plot representing time/number of nodes:
[image: Plot]
As far as I know the original Force-directed graph algorithm have complexity `O(n^2)`, but with Barnes-Hut it should be `O(nlogn)`. Yet, the plot it's not even close to nlogn.

Can someone tell me what I am doing here wrong? I've been looking at this code for quite a long now, and I don't see where I am missing something.

**EDIT:**

Based on @Ilmari Karonen answer I've run test for `MAX_LEVELS` 5, 20, 50, 100. Results are below. As it looks there is no meaningful difference I'd say (unfortunately)
[image: times]

Answer (score 3):

Just off the top of my head,

```
#define MAX_LEVELS 5
```

seems awfully low.  You may simply be running out of depth in your octree, causing your algorithm to degenerate into O(*n*²) direct summing.  You may want to try increasing `MAX_LEVELS` to a significantly higher value (at least, say, 10 or 20) and seeing if that improves the performance.

I haven't tested your code, so I can't be sure if this is the real issue, or the only one.  But it's definitely what I'd check first.

---

Looking a bit more closely at your code, I'm seeing a couple of other potential issues, too.  These might not, strictly speaking, affect performance, but they might affect the *correctness* of the results.

First, you have a `center` vector in your `Quadtree` class, presumably representing the center of mass of the nodes within the subtree, but you never seem to update that vector when adding nodes into the tree.  Since you do *use* that vector in your calculations, you might be getting bogus results because of that.

(In fact, since one thing you're using the `center` vector for is calculating the distance between a node and a subtree, and so deciding whether to descend deeper into the subtree, that might also be messing up your performance.)

Also, you seem to be updating the positions directly while traversing the tree, which means that the trajectories generated by your algorithm will depend on the order in which the nodes are traversed and the tree expanded.  For more consistent and reproducible results, you may want to first calculate the displacement of each node during the current iteration of the algorithm, storing it in a separate vector, and then run a second pass over the nodes to add the displacement to their position (and reset it for the next iterations).

Also, surely I can't be the only one who finds the fact that you have a class named `Quadtree` that implements an *oc*tree annoying, can I? :)

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your suggestions! I've run additional tests and updated my question. As for the rest of your suggestions: 1) I need to check method for calculating center of mass. 2) That's good idea. I need to test it, because indeed this might be causing some problems now when I think about it. 3) I agree that name is not 100% correct but that's only because I was reading about quadtrees at the time I was implementing it and totally forget to change the name later :)