# Confusion about leafs in octree (Barnes-Hut) algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is partially follow up question for my main question: [Optimization issues using Barnes-Hut for graph placing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033902/optimization-issues-using-barnes-hut-for-graph-placing).

I've been reading some additional implementations about Barns-Hut algorithm, and one thing is not fully clear to me. What I did is split octree up to:

- the maximum level is reached **or**
- there are no more `Element`s left (so the best situation is if there is only one child per node)

Although what I've found now is that some implementations are leaving leafs of octree empty. For me it looks strange, because if you will have more than one object on given level and this level is `nmaxLevels-1` you cannot add new element there, because according to their implementations leaf cannot has data.

So is this correct implementation with leaves left empty, or not? We all know that there is various quality code on the web.